# Why is my computed property for a date not reactive on changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Date object in my data, and I want to read the date only as a string for a date picker component (from Vuetify). The initial `date` is correctly read and displayed. I can set the date too - if I set a code breakpoint I can see that the `set` function for `date` is executed, and I can see that the `dateTime` object changes from Vue dev tools, but the computed `date` getter never updates - it stays at the initial value. What am I doing wrong?

```js
export default {
  ...
  data: function() {
    return {
      ...
      dateMenu: false,
      dateTime: new Date(),
    };
  },
  computed: {
    date: {
      get() {
        return this.dateTime.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
      },
      set(val) {
          this.dateTime.setFullYear(
          val.substr(0, 4),
          Number(val.substr(5, 2) - 1),
          val.substr(8, 2)
          );
      }
    },
    time: {
      get() {
        return this.dateTime.toISOString().substr(11, 5);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
    <v-menu
    v-model="dateMenu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    >
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="date"
        readonly
        v-on="on"
      ></v-text-field>
    </template>
    <v-date-picker
      v-model="date"
      @input="dateMenu = false"
    ></v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>
```

Comment: Is `v-text-field` not updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the value of the existing `Date` object doesn't work, as Vue isn't aware of the change. You need to set `dateTime` to a new `Date` object in order to trigger an update:

```
set(val) {
  this.dateTime = new Date(
    this.dateTime.setFullYear(
      val.substr(0, 4),
      Number(val.substr(5, 2) - 1),
      val.substr(8, 2)
    )
  );
}
```